Using ggplot in R for Likert scale values and grouping the y axis
i have a data frame in R with 2 columns A and Year as shown below :
set.seed(123)
A <- sample(1:5, 1000, replace = TRUE)
year <- sample(c(2019, 2020, 2021, 2022), 1000, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(A, year)
 A year
1 3 2021
2 3 2022
3 2 2020
4 2 2021
5 3 2022
6 5 2021

I want to create a horizontal likert chart using ggplot but in the y axis to be grouped by Year and inside each Year to have the 5 percentages as each category. Also i want the colors of each category to be 1 red, 2 light red, 3 blue , 4 light green, 5 green.
How can i do it in R ?

ggplot(df) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = year, group = A, fill = as.factor(A)), position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE))+
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(
      `1` = "red", 
      `2` = "lightpink", 
      `3` = "skyblue", 
      `4` = "lightgreen", 
      `5` = "forestgreen"),
    name = "A")

if you want to use percentages and a 100% filled bar instead of count:
ggplot(df) +
  geom_bar(
    aes(y = year, group = A, fill = as.factor(A)), 
    position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE)
  )+
  labs(x = "percent")+
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(
      `1` = "red", 
      `2` = "lightpink", 
      `3` = "skyblue", 
      `4` = "lightgreen", 
      `5` = "forestgreen"),
    name = "A")+
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1), 
    labels = scales::label_percent()
    )


one last requirement:to show the percentages on each bar in side the bar ?
